# How to install a self-written plug-in to a custom Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created an Eclipse plug-in and I can copy the `.jar` file to the `dropins` folder of my main Eclipse installation.

That works well; the plug-in runs perfectly.

Unfortunately, the plug-in is intended for another (customized) Eclipse installation which does not have a `dropins` folder. SysInternal "Process Monitor" shows that that Eclipse simply ignores the `dropins` folder if I create it.

Creating a sub-directory in `features` and placing my `.jar` file in `plugins` also does not work:

I can see that the Eclipse reads my `features.xml` but it does not make an attempt to read the `.jar` file in the `plugins` directory.

I tried to create a "Feature Project" containing the plug-in and an "Update Site Project" containing the "Feature Project":

When I try to install the plug-in from the "Update Site Project", Eclipse reports: `There are no categorized items` instead of showing me the plug-in.

"Process Monitor" shows that Eclipse does not even attempt to access the `site.xml` file.

I created the `features` and `plugins` sub-directories in my "Update Site Project" and copied the corresponding files there. Then I can select the feature to be installed; I am asked if I want to install the un-signed plug-in but then I get the message: `Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.`

I used some tool to create the files `artifacts.xml` and `content.xml`. Now I get the message `There are no categorized items` again.

I have no more ideas how to continue.

How can I install my self-written plug-in to that Eclipse installation?

Comment: Uncheck the "Group items by category" box on the Install Software dialog to avoid the "no categorized items" message .

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for your help. However, I doubt that that would help: The plug-in (including category) is shown if there is no `content.xml` file. However, in that case Eclipse does not find the plugin `.jar` file...

Comment: I found some work-around: If there is no `content.xml` file is present, Eclipse will check if the plugin `.jar` file is already installed in the Eclipse `plugins` directory. So I copy the `.jar` file of my plugin to the `plugins` directory and then perform the installation using the `Install New Software` menu command. Eclipse will not actually install the plug-in but it will start the plug-in which is already present in the `plugins` directory.

Comment: @MartinRosenau This is not how it should be done. See e.g. [_Eclipse IDE Extensions_ tutorials on vogella.com](https://vogella.com/tutorials/eclipseplatform.html) instead.

Comment: @greg-449 Un-checking the checkbox changes the message to "no items available".